# Axis of rotation and speed as the sum of 2 separate rotations

Tags: geometry, rotations

Assume that earth rotate on the ecliptic plane with a rotation of 1600 km/hr. So that it rotates without an obliquity /axial of tilt. Another celestial object hits at 24 degrees north of the equator so that it creates a new rotation of 1000 km/hr, the new rotation's plane forms a 24 degrees angle with the former rotation. Both rotations are clockwise. What is the final rotational plane and what is its rotational speed?

have included a picture, please check.

[rough sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp3i0.jpg)

I am not an expert on rotational geometry, at first I thought I can break the rotational plane with 24 degrees angle into a x and y components and adds them to the existing rotational plane, but there seems to be involved with Euler's rotation theorem and reflections, making the calculation way more complicated. is there a simplified way to work on this problem if we assumed that new rotation always occur at an angle to the existing one?

Comment: Required to find vector sum of two normals

Comment: ok...can you be more specific? sorry I feels a like total idiot, I want to make sure I follow what you said! thanks !

Comment: The resulting resultant direction and magnitude can be found out that way and we can next delete components.

Comment: isn't thats what I tried in the first place by breaking both plane into its x and y vectors and sum them up?